# Creating, Raising, and Handling Custom Events in C++ Builder (FMX)

Tags: events, event-handling, firemonkey, c++builder

I am trying to implement the following pattern and I need some help filling in the blanks:

```
// In a class, declare (and initialize?) a custom event
class Foo
{
public:
    TEvent* Bar = nullptr;
        
    Foo::Foo()
    {
        Bar = new TEvent(false);
    }
        
private:
    // This event trigger method could be called during the lifetime of a Foo object
    void Foo::TriggerMethod()
    {
        // ??? Raise Bar (pun intended :) here
    }
};
```

```
// In a separate Unit (FMXMainForm):
private:
    Foo* myFoobject = nullptr;
    
    // An event handler method
    void FMXMainForm::BarTender(TObject* Sender)
    {
        // Do stuff with event data via Sender
        ShowMessage("Bar Mitzvah!");
    }
    
public:
    // And when constructing FMXMainForm:
    __fastcall FMXMainForm::FMXMainForm(TComponent* Owner)
    {
        // Create Foo object
        myFoobject = new Foo();
        
        // Assign an event handler to myFoobject's Bar event
        // ??? myFoobject->Bar = &(this->BarTender); // This doesn't work
    }
```

Can this be done in C++ Builder/FMX? And if so, would it be via `TEvent`s? What pieces am I missing? I need some help, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is quite doable in C++Builder, but it is done a little bit differently than what you have shown, ie utilizing [`Classes::TNotifyEvent`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TNotifyEvent) instead of [`Syncobjs::TEvent`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SyncObjs.TEvent) (which deals only with thread synchronization and nothing to do with object events), eg:

```cpp
#include <fmx.h>
#include <System.Classes.hpp>
...

// In a class, declare (and initialize?) a custom event
class Foo : public TObject
{
public:
    TNotifyEvent Bar = nullptr;

private:
    // This event trigger method could be called during the lifetime of a Foo object
    void TriggerMethod()
    {
        if (Bar) Bar(this);
    }
};
```

```cpp
// In a separate Unit (FMXMainForm):
private:
    Foo* myFoobject = nullptr;
    
    // An event handler method
    void __fastcall BarTender(TObject* Sender)
    {
        // Do stuff with event data via Sender
        ShowMessage("Bar Mitzvah!");
    }
    
public:
    // And when constructing FMXMainForm:
    __fastcall FMXMainForm(TComponent* Owner)
    {
        // Create Foo object
        myFoobject = new Foo();
        
        // Assign an event handler to myFoobject's Bar event
        myFoobject->Bar = &BarTender;
    }
```

Later on, if you want to add additional parameters to the event, simply replace `TNotifyEvent` with a custom type that includes the desired parameters, eg:

```cpp
#include <fmx.h>

typedef void __fastcall (__closure *TMyEventType)(... param types here ...);
// or:
// using TMyEventType = void __fastcall (__closure *)(... param types here ...);

...

// In a class, declare (and initialize?) a custom event
class Foo : public TObject
{
public:
    TMyEventType Bar = nullptr;

private:
    // This event trigger method could be called during the lifetime of a Foo object
    void TriggerMethod()
    {
        if (Bar) Bar(... param values here ...);
    }
};
```

```cpp
// In a separate Unit (FMXMainForm):
private:
    Foo* myFoobject = nullptr;
    
    // An event handler method
    void __fastcall BarTender(... params here ...)
    {
        // Do stuff with event data via Sender
        ShowMessage("Bar Mitzvah!");
    }
    
public:
    // And when constructing FMXMainForm:
    __fastcall FMXMainForm(TComponent* Owner)
    {
        // Create Foo object
        myFoobject = new Foo();
        
        // Assign an event handler to myFoobject's Bar event
        myFoobject->Bar = &BarTender;
    }
```

---

Note that the above approach does rely on a number of Embarcadero-specific compiler extensions, namely:

- the [`__fastcall`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Fastcall,_fastcall) calling convention.
- the [`__closure`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Closure) keyword (used in the declaration of `TNotifyEvent`), which allows a pointer-to-member-function to point at a member function of any class type, unlike a [standard C++ pointer-to-member-function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_member_functions), which is class-specific.
- a non-standard `operator&` that creates a pointer-to-member-function via an object pointer/reference, which is compatible with `__closure`.
- the Delphi-based [`TObject`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.TObject) base class.

If you want a pure C++ solution, try [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) instead, eg:

```cpp
#include <functional>

// In a class, declare (and initialize?) a custom event
class Foo
{
public:
    std::function<void()> Bar;

private:
    // This event trigger method could be called during the lifetime of a Foo object
    void TriggerMethod()
    {
        if (Bar) Bar();
    }
};
```

```cpp
// In a separate Unit (FMXMainForm):
private:
    Foo* myFoobject = nullptr;
    
    // An event handler method
    void BarTender()
    {
        // Do stuff with event data via Sender
        ShowMessage("Bar Mitzvah!");
    }
    
public:
    // And when constructing FMXMainForm:
    __fastcall FMXMainForm(TComponent* Owner)
    {
        // Create Foo object
        myFoobject = new Foo();
        
        // Assign an event handler to myFoobject's Bar event
        myFoobject->Bar = std::bind(&FMXMainForm::BarTender, this);
        or:
        myFoobject->Bar = [this]{ BarTender(); };
    }
```

Or, using additional parameters:

```cpp
#include <functional>

// In a class, declare (and initialize?) a custom event
class Foo
{
public:
    std::function<void(... param types here ...)> Bar;

private:
    // This event trigger method could be called during the lifetime of a Foo object
    void TriggerMethod()
    {
        if (Bar) Bar(... param values here ...);
    }
};
```

```cpp
// In a separate Unit (FMXMainForm):
private:
    Foo* myFoobject = nullptr;
    
    // An event handler method
    void BarTender(... params here ...)
    {
        // Do stuff with event data via Sender
        ShowMessage("Bar Mitzvah!");
    }
    
public:
    // And when constructing FMXMainForm:
    __fastcall FMXMainForm(TComponent* Owner)
    {
        // Create Foo object
        myFoobject = new Foo();
        
        // Assign an event handler to myFoobject's Bar event
        using namespace std::placeholders;
        myFoobject->Bar = std::bind(&FMXMainForm::BarTender, this, ... _1, _2, etc ...);
        or:
        myFoobject->Bar = [this](... params here ...){
            BarTender(... params here ...);
        };
    }
```

Comment: This works great and answers my original question perfectly. And while this covers my bases so far, it is not unfathomable that I might need to dispatch and trigger parametrized events at some point down the line. Embarcadero's `TNotifyEvent` documentation states that it is "used for events that do not require parameters".

Comment: Another `docwiki` page however (https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Calling_the_Event) hints that it is possible to dispatch/trigger custom events with parameters:
`virtual void __fastcall TComponentName::DoEventName(UnicodeString Parameter1, UnicodeString Parameter2)` and then the trigger part `if (FOnEventName) FOnEventName(this, Parameter1, Parameter2);`
So my follow up question is how to create and use parametrized events?

Comment: @Makaveli84 I updated my answer to show that

Comment: Another follow-up to this question: Is there a way to assign lambda handlers to an FMX control's TNotifyEvent? For example: `Control->OnClick = [this](TObject* Sender){ DoThings(); };` does not work. Errors are: `[bccaarm Error] Source.cpp(#): no viable conversion from '<lambda at Source.cpp:#:#>' to 'System::Classes::TNotifyEvent' (aka ...)` and `FMX.Controls.hpp(501): passing argument to parameter 'Value' here`

Comment: @Makaveli84 A lambda can't be *directly* assigned to a `__closure` (which `TNotifyEvent` uses), so that code will not work, no. However,  a *non-capturing* lambda is convertible to a C-style function pointer (a *capturing* lambda is not), which CAN be assigned to a `__closure` *indirectly* via the `TMethod` struct, eg: `TMethod m; m.Data = nullptr; m.Code = [](void*, TObject*){ DoThings(); }; Control->OnClick = reinterpret_cast<TNotifyEvent&>(m);`

Comment: This is good knowledge to acquire. I need to read up more on lambdas and the difference between capturing and non-capturing. That being said, I think the too-many steps to assign a non-capturing lambda to a `__closure` and make this work beats the purpose of streamlining the handling of certain events via inline lambdas.. Thanks for the info.